# Counting the data from the database to calculate the percentage calculation in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'Materniteti');
    $f = "select count(*) as f from neonatologji where gjinia=1"; 
    $m = "select count(*) as m from neonatologji where gjinia=2"; 

    $s = $f + $m;

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $s); 
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $row["s"];
    $percentage = number_format( $f / $s ) * 100 . '%';

?>
```

I wanted to make a percentage calculation where the program selects all the female gender and saves the number in `$f` and all the the male gender in `$m` and in `$s` should be saved the sum of `f` and `m`. But the program doesn't recognize the `$m` and so the `$s` doesn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many issues with the given code.

Never use * with count, as you have to count only rows then an individual column is sufficient. So replace the following line:

```
$f = "select count(*) as f from neonatologji where gjinia=1";
```

to

```
$f = "select count(id) as f from neonatologji where gjinia=1";
```

Select query return ResultSet. You cannot use it directly, you have to convert it to an array by using `fetch_array()`.